# How to create Matplotlib figure with image and profile plots that fit together?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 2d

I would like to plot 2d data as an image, with profile plots through along the x and y axis displayed below and to the side. It's a pretty common way to display data so there may be an easier way to approach this. I would like to find the most simple and robust way that does so correctly, and without using anything outside of matplotlib (though I would be interested in knowing of other packages that may be particularly relevant). In particular, the method should work without changing anything if the shape (aspect ratio) of the data changes.

My main issue is getting the side plots to scale correctly so their borders match up with main plot.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
# generate grid and test data
x, y = np.linspace(-3,3,300), np.linspace(-1,1,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
def f(x,y) :
    return np.exp(-(x**2/4+y**2)/.2)*np.cos((x**2+y**2)*10)**2
data = f(X,Y)

# 2d image plot with profiles
h, w = data.shape
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2,width_ratios=[w,w*.2], height_ratios=[h,h*.2])
ax = [plt.subplot(gs[0]),plt.subplot(gs[1]),plt.subplot(gs[2])]
bounds = [x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()]
ax[0].imshow(data, cmap='gray', extent = bounds, origin='lower')
ax[1].plot(data[:,w/2],Y[:,w/2],'.',data[:,w/2],Y[:,w/2])
ax[1].axis([data[:,w/2].max(), data[:,w/2].min(), Y.min(), Y.max()])
ax[2].plot(X[h/2,:],data[h/2,:],'.',X[h/2,:],data[h/2,:])
plt.show()
```

As you can see from the output below, the way things are scaled the image to the right does not properly match the boundaries.

Partial solutions:

1) Manually play with the figure size to find the right aspect ratio so that it appears correctly (could do automatically using the image ratio + padding + the width ratios used?). Seems tacky when there are already so many options for packing that are supposed to take care of these things automatically. **EDIT:** `plt.gcf().set_figheight(f.get_figwidth()*h/w)` seems to work if padding is not changed.

2) Add `ax[0].set_aspect('auto')` , which then makes boundaries line up, but the image no longer has the correct aspect ratio.

Output from code sample above:
[image: Example output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `sharex` and `sharey` to do this, replace your `ax=` line with this:

```
ax = [plt.subplot(gs[0]),]
ax.append(plt.subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax[0]))
ax.append(plt.subplot(gs[2], sharex=ax[0]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to do the trick. At least, it looked good with the few things I tested it with. In particular, when changing the figure size or padding with `plt.gcf().tight_layout(h_pad=0, w_pad=0)` it leaves things aligned.

Comment: Yep, changing the figure size etc changes them together. The shared axes are linked, which is useful in interactive environments.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to generate your layout by using `subplot` and `gridspec`, while still preserving (1) the ratio of the axes and (2) the limits imposed on the axis. An alternative solution would be to place your axes manually in your figure instead and to control the size of the figure accordingly (as you already mentioned in your OP). Although this requires more work than using `subplot` and `gridspec`, this approach remains quite simple and can be very powerful and flexible to produce complex layouts where a fine control over the margins and the placement of the axes is desired.

Below is an example that shows how this can be achieve by setting the size of the figure accordingly to the size given to the axes. Inversely, it would also be possible to fit the axes within a figure of a predefined size. The aspect ratio of the axes would then be kept by using the figure margins as a buffer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

#------------------------------------------------------------ generate data ----

# generate grid and test data
x, y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 300), np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
def f(x,y) :
    return np.exp(-(x**2/4+y**2)/.2)*np.cos((x**2+y**2)*10)**2
data = f(X,Y)

# 2d image plot with profiles
h, w = data.shape
data_ratio = h / float(w)

#------------------------------------------------------------ create figure ----

#--- define axes lenght in inches ----

width_ax0 = 8.
width_ax1 = 2.
height_ax2 = 2.

height_ax0 = width_ax0 * data_ratio

#---- define margins size in inches ----

left_margin  = 0.65
right_margin = 0.2
bottom_margin = 0.5
top_margin = 0.25
inter_margin = 0.5

#--- calculate total figure size in inches ----

fwidth = left_margin + right_margin + inter_margin + width_ax0 + width_ax1
fheight = bottom_margin + top_margin + inter_margin + height_ax0 + height_ax2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fwidth, fheight))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

#---------------------------------------------------------------- create axe----

ax0 = fig.add_axes([left_margin / fwidth,
                    (bottom_margin + inter_margin + height_ax2) / fheight,
                    width_ax0 / fwidth, height_ax0 / fheight])

ax1 = fig.add_axes([(left_margin + width_ax0 + inter_margin) / fwidth,
                    (bottom_margin + inter_margin + height_ax2) / fheight,
                     width_ax1 / fwidth, height_ax0 / fheight])

ax2 = fig.add_axes([left_margin / fwidth, bottom_margin / fheight,
                    width_ax0 / fwidth, height_ax2 / fheight])

#---------------------------------------------------------------- plot data ----

bounds = [x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()]
ax0.imshow(data, cmap='gray', extent = bounds, origin='lower')
ax1.plot(data[:,w/2],Y[:,w/2],'.',data[:,w/2],Y[:,w/2])
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax2.plot(X[h/2,:], data[h/2,:], '.', X[h/2,:], data[h/2,:])

plt.show(block=False)
fig.savefig('subplot_layout.png')
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Yea, that is it a bit more work. It's a nice example of what to do if you need more direct control though.

Comment: @argentum2f Thanks. It basically comes down to what the figures thus generated are used for. Since I mostly produce publication quality figures for technical papers, with a strict and condensed layout, I usually end up doing things manually to get exactly what I want. For the dynamic exploration of data on-sceen however, this approach is sub-optimal, I concede.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly the solution with **sharex** and **sharey** do not work for me. They align the axis ranges but **not the axis lengths**! 
To have them aligned reliably I added:

```py
pos  = ax[0].get_position()
pos1 = ax[1].get_position()
pos2 = ax[2].get_position()
ax[1].set_position([pos1.x0,pos.y0,pos1.width,pos.height])
ax[2].set_position([pos.x0,pos2.y0,pos.width,pos2.height])
```

So in context with the earlier answer from CT Zhu this makes:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
# generate grid and test data
x, y = np.linspace(-3,3,300), np.linspace(-1,1,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
def f(x,y) :
    return np.exp(-(x**2/4+y**2)/.2)*np.cos((x**2+y**2)*10)**2

data = f(X,Y)

# 2d image plot with profiles
h, w = data.shape
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2,width_ratios=[w,w*.2], height_ratios=[h,h*.2])
ax = [plt.subplot(gs[0]),]
ax.append(plt.subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax[0]))
ax.append(plt.subplot(gs[2], sharex=ax[0]))
bounds = [x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()]
ax[0].imshow(data, cmap='gray', extent = bounds, origin='lower')
ax[1].plot(data[:,int(w/2)],Y[:,int(w/2)],'.',data[:,int(w/2)],Y[:,int(w/2)])
ax[1].axis([data[:,int(w/2)].max(), data[:,int(w/2)].min(), Y.min(), Y.max()])
ax[2].plot(X[int(h/2),:],data[int(h/2),:],'.',X[int(h/2),:],data[int(h/2),:])
pos  = ax[0].get_position()
pos1 = ax[1].get_position()
pos2 = ax[2].get_position()
ax[1].set_position([pos1.x0,pos.y0,pos1.width,pos.height])
ax[2].set_position([pos.x0,pos2.y0,pos.width,pos2.height])
plt.show()
```